# Get JSON values to form an Object

Tags: java, json, types, gson

Using **GSON** :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(response);
System.out.println(json);
```

I receive the following **JSON** representation of a **User**:

```
"{\"userID\":\"user2\",\"firstName\":\"Maria\",\"lastName\":\"Silva\",\"birthDate\":\"Ago 1, 2012\",\"gender\":\"Female\"}"
```

Now, I want to get those values to construct a **User object** (doing User.setuserID, userObj.setFirstName, ... )

How can I get the correspond values to set the User values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gson` will do that for you. You need not worry about it. That's the power of `Gson`.

```
User object = gson.fromJson(jsonString, User.class); // Fully populated User object.
```

Comment: Thanks! it seems really simple.

Comment: Another question: but if I want to print, for example, the String `object.getEmail()`, how can I do it? It tells me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING`

Comment: I don't see `Email` in the json.

Comment: i didn't put there all the User fields. There are more.

Comment: If your json has all the fields, it'll populate the whole object. Else, it won't populate fields which are not available in the json.

Comment: But I have all the fields populated. It was supposed to can do something like `System.out.print(object.getEmail());`?

Comment: `"{\"userID\":\"user2\",\"FirstName\":\"Maria\",\"LastName\":\"Silva\",\"ISOcountrycode\":\"PT\",\"Telephone\":\"+911111111\",\"isMale\":false,\"Email\":\"ma@abc.pt\",\"Birthdate\":\"Ago 1, 2012\",\"isObject\":false}"`

And my User have this methods: `public String  getuserID(); public String  getFirstName(); public String  getLastName(); public String  getISOcountrycode(); public String  getTelephone(); public Date    getBirthdate(); public boolean getisMale(); public String  getEmail(); public boolean getisObject(); `